# Symfony 1.4 compatible I18N translation system?

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony1, symfony-1.4, xliff

I am migrating a small app from Symfony into a separate project, and the only
Symfony component that it depends on is I18N string translation. By example:

- `action.class.php`:

  ```
  $this->culture = 'pt_BR';
  ```
- `templates/search_box.php`:

  ```
  <h1><?php echo __('Destination') ?></h1>
  ```
- `i18n/pt_BR/messages.xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <xliff version="1.0">
    <file datatype="plaintext" source-language="en"
          target-language="pt_BR" original="messages">
      <body>
        <note>
          SEARCH BOX
        </note>
        <trans-unit id="0">
          <source>Destination</source>
          <target>Destino</target>
        </trans-unit>
      </body>
    </file>
  </xliff>
  ```

*Is there a similar, preferably compatible system, available as a PHP package?*

I am interested in keeping the `xml` file with translations, but I could also
live with a different format.

## Update

What I have now, inspired by @akky's answer:

- `composer.json`:

  ```
  {
      "name": "example/layout",
      "description":
      "Provides common layout components such as header / footer.",
      "license": "proprietary",
      "require": {
          "symfony/translation": "2.4.*",
          "symfony/config": "~2.0"
      }
  }
  ```
- `i18n/messages.pt_BR.xliff`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <xliff xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2" version="1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="messages">
      <body>
        <trans-unit id="0">
          <source>Destination</source>
          <target>Destino</target>
        </trans-unit>
      </body>
    </file>
  </xliff>
  ```

  Unfortunately, the `<note>` element caused an error messages, and so I
   removed it.
- `public/helper.inc.php`:

  ```
  <?php

  require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';

  use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
  use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
  use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader;
  use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader;
  use Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\FileResource;

  $loader = new XliffFileLoader();
  $catalogue = $loader->load('../i18n/messages.pt_BR.xliff', 'pt_BR');

  function __($text) {
    global $catalogue;
    return $catalogue->get($text);
  }
  ```
- `public/header.php`:

  ```
  <?php require_once('helper.inc.php') ?>

  <h1><?php echo __('Destination') ?></h1>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the resource file format is XLIFF. You may find XLIFF handling php packages, as well as xliff2(your favorite i18n format) converters.

You may use [Symfony Components Translation](https://github.com/symfony/Translation) even if you are not using Symfony in the new project. Composer and autoload will make it available on your regular php project. I recommend it.

Comment: I tried the Symfony Translation component, and followed up with [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063982), because I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: See my updated answer. Using Symfony 2's translation component sort of worked, but I had to remove the `<note>` tag.

Comment: That composer.json in your update seems to have some redundant lines. If you are a package user, you usually need only "require" parts. Other lines may be for when you make and offer a composer package to others.

Comment: I had issues with `composer install` not following dependencies. That's why I added the extra fields, to make `composer validate` happy. Eventually, I manually added `symfony/config`, which is needed by `symfony/translation`. It was not automatically installed as dependency.