# Use Symfony 2 component in non-Symfony project?

Tags: php, symfony, internationalization, xliff

For getting XLIFF/2 support in PHP, in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057407/282729), it was suggested to
use the Symfony 2 Translation component.

So I downloaded it [from Github](https://github.com/symfony/Translation) into a directory `../vendor/` and naively
tried to use it:

```
<?php

    require_once '../vendor/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php';
    require_once '../vendor/Symfony/Component/Translation/MessageSelector.php';
    require_once '../vendor/Symfony/Component/Translation/Loader/ArrayLoader.php';

    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader;

    $translator = new Translator('fr_FR', new MessageSelector());
```

This doesn’t work as other components would need to be loaded:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'Symfony\\Component\\Translation\\TranslatorInterface' not found in /home/ec2-user/layout/vendor/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php on line 25
```

Now, I could manually add a `require_once` for every file, until all
dependencies are met, but I’m not sure if that’s the proper approach.

*How do I use a single Symfony 2 component in a non-Symfony project? Is that a
bad idea?*

Comment: Better use [composer](https://getcomposer.org) for autoload classes

Comment: Also show path to your file where you want to include translator, please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manage your dependencies with **composer**.

First create a `composer.json` file in your project folder :

```
{
    "require": {
        "symfony/translation": "2.4.*"
    }
}
```

Then download composer and run it :

```
wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install
```

You can now use your component by importing the composer autoloader :

```
<?php

    require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector;
    use Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\ArrayLoader;

    $translator = new Translator('fr_FR', new MessageSelector());
    $translator->setFallbackLocales(array('fr'));
    $translator->addLoader('array', new ArrayLoader());
    $translator->addResource('array', array(
        'Hello World!' => 'Bonjour',
    ), 'fr');

    echo $translator->trans('Hello World!')."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

What about using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) to manage your dependencies.

The point here is that it also manages autoloading,

**From the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/),**

> **Autoloading[#](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#autoloading)**
>
> Besides downloading the library, Composer also prepares an autoload
> file that's capable of autoloading all of the classes in any of the
> libraries that it downloads. To use it, just add the following line to
> your code's bootstrap process:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```